# How to capture photo through webcam with react-native-windows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-windows

I am building a desktop app using react-native-windows and want to capture a photo using webcam. Currently i am working with react-native-camera to achieve this. But camera is not being accessed, when I gone through their [documentation] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access#add-capability-declarations-to-the-app-manifest) its asking me to write c# code but i am not having any idea.